# Wait for external method to complete before finishing?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

I'm making a little calendar app, in PHP and JavaScript. To populate the events `div` on the first page, I run this function:

```
function populateEvents() {

    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
        url: "populateEvents.php",
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {  
            $('#events').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus + ". Error thrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Pretty simple, `populateEvents.php` does most of the work.

Now, when I want to add an event, I call the following function:

```
function createEvent(u_id) {
    var title = $("#titleInput").val();
    var type = $("#typeSelect").val();
    var location = $("#locationInput").val();
    var date = $("#inputDate").val();
    var time = $("#inputTime").val();
    var allday = $('#allDaySelect:checked').val() !== undefined ? '1' : '0';
    var duedate = type == 'todo' ? date : '';
    var notes = $("#inputNotes").val();
    var output = 'u_id=' + u_id + '&title=' + title + '&type=' + type + '&location=' + location + '&date=' + date + '&time=' + time + '&allday=' + allday + '&duedate=' + duedate + '&notes=' + notes;


    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
        url: "addEvent.php", 
        data: output,
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {  
            if (data == '') {
                toggleNewEvent();
                populateEvents();
            } else {
                // extract form problems from formProblems, in form: title=empty&date=empty&...

                var errorArray = data.split("&");
                var fields = '';
                $.each(errorArray, function(index, value) {
                    var field;
                    var smallArray = value.split("=");
                    field = smallArray[0];
                    fields = fields + field + ', ';
                });
                alert('You must fill in the following fields: ' + fields);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus + ". Error thrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

A bit more complicated, but I'm sure you get the gist. Values sent to `addEvent.php`, return string parsed, etc, events repopulated. Now, I just restructured the whole PHP side, to implement an `eventlist` class and an event class. Previously, the `addevent.php` file did all the actual backend work, but now, that file (after some validation) boils down to this:

```
if ($return == '') {
        /*If return is empty, everything is fine, carry on.*/
        $eventlist->addEvent($u_id, $title, $type, $date, $time, $allday, $location, $dueby, $notes);
    } else {
        /*Throw an error*/
        echo ($return);
    }
```

As a result however, this file returns to the JavaScript function when it's sent that request to the `eventlist` object to execute the `addEvent` method. The function then tries to populate the event div immediately, and as a result, it doesn't work, because the `addEvent` method hasn't finished. When you refresh the page, however, it works fine, so I know it is inserting them correctly, it just needs to wait for that second PHP file to finish.

Comment: Please.. **do not use a string as the `data` param**. You can pass an object which will relieve you from having to take care about escaping things.

Comment: How can I pass an object between javascript and php.

Comment: he means the `output` variable should be a json object, that way jquery will escape any texts and pass the proper data, e.g. `{u_id':1,'title':'this is my title'}`

Comment: I've never taken the time to learn JSON, but that sounds like a really good idea.. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not return the `$eventlist->addEvent($u_id, $title, $type.......` part to the script,
`echo $eventlist->addEvent($u_id, $title, $type.......`.

Then in your `addEvent` method return something, i.e. the ID of the event.

Then instead of checking the page is blank, you are checking for an ID **(** *`if (!isNaN(data))` isNotANumber* **)**, thus you know you have finished inserting your event as your page wouldn't return until it has the ID.

Comment: This is a great idea, if only I could get it to work. I'm getting the following error from addEvent.php:

Call to a member function addEvent() on a non-object in /home/content/53/7316853/html/organiser/home/addEvent.php on line 44

line 44 is: $return = $eventlist->addEvent($u_id, $title, $type, $date, $time, $allday, $location, $dueby, $notes);

Comment: Never mind, I was using a session variable to store a serialized version of my event list object, and my session expired :P